# C#: Any tool to automatically generate Interfaces from Classes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm using the Entity Framework and I want to generate an Interface class from each of my Entity classes.

Is there a tool out there that can run through each class do this automatically for me so i don't have to do it one by one?

Answer (score 14):

[alt text http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/JaySmith/WindowsLiveWriter/WCFSyndicationPodcatcherSample_14752/ExtractInterface_01_2.jpg](http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/JaySmith/WindowsLiveWriter/WCFSyndicationPodcatcherSample_14752/ExtractInterface_01_2.jpg)

Comment: This is a built in Visual Studio thing, in case you didn't recognise it.

Comment: That's good, but is there a tool that can run through my, say 100 entities, and generate so i don't have to do it manually for each one?

Comment: You need to generate 100 interfaces from existing classes?  Why?

Comment: Because i want to implement the answer to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699487/entity-framework-separation-of-concerns

Comment: So any suggestions on a third party tool guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ProxyInterfaceSourceGenerator](https://github.com/StefH/ProxyInterfaceSourceGenerator) which can generate interfaces + proxy classes for defined classes.

*Example*:

**Given: an external existing class which does not implement an interface**

```cs
public sealed class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string HelloWorld(string name)
    {
        return $"Hello {name} !";
    }
}
```

**Create a partial interface**

And annotate this with `ProxyInterfaceGenerator.Proxy[...]` and with the Type which needs to be wrapped:

```cs
[ProxyInterfaceGenerator.Proxy(typeof(Person))]
public partial interface IPerson
{
}
```

When the code is compiled, this source generator creates the following:

**1. An additional partial interface**
Which defines the same properties and methods as in the external class.

```cs
public partial interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    string HelloWorld(string name);
}
```

**2. A Proxy class**

Which takes the external class in the constructor and wraps all public properties, events and methods.

```cs
public class PersonProxy : IPerson
{
    public Person _Instance { get; }

    /// code here ...
}
```